# What background image do you use on your terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, style

What images/styles do you use for your terminal profile? I'm looking for a visual upgrade from the stock style.

Comment: This would be better suited for a forum/discussion piece on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) - for more information on [What questions work here](http://askubuntu.com/faq#WikiPlaceholder-FaqWhatKindOfQuestions) check our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Original image is [here](http://chon-chan.deviantart.com/art/Gothic-face-Wallpaper1680-1050-66384091).